# Marking areas in a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose I want to mark the area defined by the following equation:

$$\max(\mid x_1-a \mid,\mid x_2-b \mid) \leq c$$

for any real constants $a$, $b$, and $c$.

How do I do that in Mathematica? I can draw the border for the area by using the `ContourPlot` and and changing the inequality sign to an equality sign, but is there a way I can mark the area?

The above equation is just an example. In general, I am looking for a solution to mark the area given by any implicit function of the form $f(x_1,x_2) \leq c$ for a real constant $c$.

Comment: Take a look at [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot)

Comment: check [RegionPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot.html), For example, `Manipulate[ RegionPlot[  Max[Abs[x - a], Abs[y - b]] <= c, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {a, -1, 
  1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = 5;
b = 10;
c = 7;
RegionPlot[
 Max[Abs[x - a], Abs[y - b]] <= c, 
 {x, -20, 20}, 
 {y, -20, 20}]
```

[image: RegionPlot]